# How to see if an array has 2 or more elements that are the same?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array, and I want to check if any of the elements in the array are duplicated.

```js
["item1", "item2", "item3"] //false All the items are unique
["item1", "item2", "item1"] //true There are 2 of the same items.
```

Comment: Any item? Or a specific one (like "item1")?

Comment: Convert the array to a `Set`. If the set and array have the same number of elements, they're all unique.

Comment: A specific one like "item1"

Comment: Be careful with "same" and "duplicated"

Comment: So it would be false for `["item1", "item2", "item2"]`?

Comment: `["item1", "item2", "item2"]` whould be false for "item1" but not "item2"

Comment: That's not what was asked. It's either true or false for the entire array.

Comment: Read the 3rd comment.

Comment: @Haytam That's why I wanted clarification from the OP (I didn't read carefully and assumed your comment was from OP).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way is to use a `Set`.

```js
function doesContainDups(array) {
   let set = new Set(array);
   return set.size !== array.length;
}

console.log(doesContainDups(["item1", "item2", "item3"]));
console.log(doesContainDups(["item1", "item2", "item1"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the array is filled with only strings, you can use a set.
Create a set from the array, then compare the array length to the set size. If they are the same, then they are unique. If they are different, there is a a duplicate. Here is a simple example.

```js
const arr1 = ["item1", "item2", "item3"];
const arr2 = ["item1", "item2", "item1"];
const setFromArr1 = new Set(arr1);
const setFromArr2 = new Set(arr2);
const arr1AllUnique = arr1.length === setFromArr1.size;
const arr2AllUnique = arr2.length === setFromArr2.size;
console.log(arr1AllUnique);
console.log(arr2AllUnique);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to test if an array includes duplicates of a specific item.

Usage: `containsDuplicateOf(yourArray, "item1")`

```js
function containsDuplicateOf(array, item) {
   for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       const current = array[i];
       let count = 0;
       for (let j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
           if (array[j] === current)
               count++;
               
           if (count > 1) return true;
       }
   }

   return false;
}
```